# How to convert all png files to jpg using convert.exe with batch code

Tags: batch-file

I found a code that convert my png file to jpg but it just convert the file i linked not all files
My code:

`convert product.Png -background white product.jpg`

But i need a code to convert all files in folders and subfolders to jpg

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. [so] isn't a script writing service. There are literally hundreds of examples how to iterate (sub-)dirs to find files and process them one by one. Use the search box above to find them.

Comment: You could use PowerShell https://dejanstojanovic.net/powershell/2018/march/converting-existing-website-images-to-google-webp-using-powershell/

Comment: You can use the `FOR` command with the `R` option to get a list of all your png files.  It will span the directory tree.  You can then use the `FOR` commands meta variable with your `convert` command.

Comment: Yes but i did it before
For /R %%I in (".png") do (
Convert *.png -background white -flattern "%%~fI.png"
)

So what is my probleme

Answer (score 1):

The FOR /R command will iterate each file found in the directory tree.  So you want to use the FOR meta variable in your convert command.  I am not overly familiar with the syntax of the CONVERT program, but I assume the input file name is listed first and the output file is listed last.  I am going to assume you want the output file in the same directory as the input file.

```
FOR /R %%G IN (*.png) DO convert "%%~G" -background white "%%~dpnG.jpg"
```

This needs to be run from a batch file.  If you run it from the command line then you only use one percent symbol.